# Why can't I use var in this instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using the code below and for some reason I can't use var to declare my variable. I am brand new to asp/c# so please go easy on me. I've had a look around and I can't find the correct way of doing this:

```
var brandslist = from brand in brandDB.brands
                         join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                         orderby brand_family.brand_family_name
                         orderby brand.priority
                         orderby brand.genre_id
                         select brand_family.brand_family_name, priority, roll_image;
```

Thanks to anyone who can tell me the correct method of making this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a local variable and the query itself were valid, you would be able to.

However, the query expression is invalid. Just looking at the last line, this:

```
select brand_family.brand_family_name, priority, roll_image;
```

should probably be:

```
select new { brand_family.brand_family_name,
             brand.priority,
             brand.roll_image };
```

It's worth looking closely at the compiler error - it generally gives a reasonably good explanation of what's wrong.

Next up, your ordering is almost certainly wrong - I very much doubt that this does what you want it to. To express multiple orderings, you typically just list them, separated by commas, like this:

```
var brandslist = from brand in brandDB.brands
                 join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family
                   on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                 orderby brand_family.brand_family_name,
                         brand.priority,
                         brand.order_id
                 select new { brand_family.brand_family_name,
                              brand.priority,
                              brand.roll_image };
```

This will translate to an `OrderBy` call followed by subsequent `ThenBy` calls - treating `brand_family_name` as the *primary* sort ordering, and the others as secondary orderings.

Comment: +1 for the advice to look a the compiler error. Although I must admit compiler messages seemed a little cryptic to me when I was inexperienced.

Comment: much thanks to you sir! if i could buy you a beer I would! Still getting used to the cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed :D

```
var brandslist = from brand in brandDB.brands
                 join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                 orderby brand_family.brand_family_name,
                         brand.priority,
                         brand.genre_id
                 select new {brand_family.brand_family_name, brand.priority, brand.roll_image};
```

Comment: Not quite - `priority` and `roll_image` aren't in scope.

Answer (score 0):

var exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type. In your select brand_family.brand_family_name, priority, roll_image;
you are returning multiple items.

Comment: var has nothing to do with enumerators.  It is a variable declaration that assigns the type of the declared variable to be the compile-time type of the expression being assigned to it.

Comment: @recursive: var exposes enumerator in this particular case. if you implement this error prone code, you will get that help instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fix it but try this:

```
var brandslist = (from brand in brandDB.brands
                         join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                         orderby brand_family.brand_family_name
                         orderby brand.priority
                         orderby brand.genre_id
                         select new { brand_family.brand_family_name, priority, roll_image } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also fix your orderby or else you are just reordering

```
orderby brand_family.brand_family_name
orderby brand.priority
orderby brand.genre_id
```

Should become

`orderby brand_family.brand_family_name, brand.priority, brand.genre_id`